# Deriving 5 V and 3.3 V from 12 V using single IC

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator

I am making a college project which requires me to use a 5 V LCD display and a 3.3 V microcontroller.

I am using a 12 V power adapter to power to complete circuit.

I am using LM7805 and LM3940 to generate 5 V, and 3.3V, respectively. Is there any IC that takes in 12 V and spits out 2 or more voltage levels like 3.3 V, 5 V, 9 V etc?

If such ICs exist then what is the IC classified as? (like 7805 is a linear voltage regulator).

The IC I require should do something like this:- [image]

Comment: I have seen up to 8 dc-dc channels from a single device, so yes, three is pretty common, check out either the "DC-DC switching regulators" or the "Linear" sections of Digikey's "Integrated Circuits (ICs) " page, last I checked there was 334 dc-dc regulators with 3 or more outputs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using a linear regulator of any kind to get 5V from 12V is very inefficient. 3.3V is even worse. To get 0.15A at 5V (0.75W) will waste more than 1W in the regulator and will likely require at least a small heatsink. You could consider using a switching regulator.

One method that is sometimes useful is to derive 5V from the 12V with a switching regulator (or use a 5V source to begin with) and then derive the 3.3 from the 5V with a linear regulator. This works best if the current from the 5V is relatively high (for example for an LCD with backlight which might require 100mA) and the current from the 3.3V supply is relatively low (for example a typical 8-bit micro which might only require 10mA). In that case, an SOT-23 regulator could probably be used.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any IC that takes in 12 V and spits out 2 or more voltage levels like 3.3 V, 5 V, 9 V etc?

Yes, certainly – but they won't get easier than using two linear regulators – the amount of external components (in this case, only in- and output capacitors) cannot be reduced.

> If such ICs exist then what is the IC classified as (like 7805 is a linear voltage regulator).

"Voltage Regulators with multiple outputs"

Now, what you ask is basically a shopping recommendation, and thus, would be off-topic here, so let's rater conclude a list of things you need to decide:

- Ranges of input voltage
- Nominal output voltages, acceptable deviations from those
- Currents on each of these outputs that your supply needs offer

With those information, go to the website of semiconductor manufacturers, and use their "power supply design" tools.

Typical companies are

- [Texas Instruments](http://ti.com)
- [Maxim](http://maximintegrated.com)
- [Linear Technology](http://linear.com)
- [ST Micro](http://st.com)
- ...

All of them have tables of their voltage regulator products, and many of them also have tools where you just type in the data that you've compiled, and they spit out possible components and propose circuit designs.

As said, in your scenario, having two separate regulators, one for 5 V, and one for 3.3 V, is definitely the easiest solution. It's common to see a cascade of power supplies – i.e. the first stage would convert 12 V -> 5 V, and the second stage just 5 V -> 3.3 V, to avoid "burning" (12-3.3) V = 8.7 V in a single supply IC.

Comment: RE: "to avoid "burning" (12-3.3) V = 8.7 V in a single supply IC." You realize, but not all readers do, that there's no free lunch in this scenario. This method only moves power consumption from the 3.3 V regulator to the 5 V regulator. It's only a matter of details (what size heat sinks you have and need, what chips you can get for what price, etc) whether it's a good thing to do or not.

Comment: @ThePhoton absolutely right! Also, this cascaded design often is used to implement the high-voltage drop using a high-efficient, yet noisy, Switch Mode Power Supply, and then generate the noise-sensitive voltage using an LDO; again, the right choice usually is made based on design requirements that clearly leave the scope of the question!

Answer (score 4):

There are many dual rail regulators on the market, but they tend to be for specialized applications and mass produced itmes.

There is this from OnSemi: http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/ENA1982-D.PDF

...and this: http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/MC33762-D.PDF ...which might just work for you.

Answer (score 1):

sure!you can do this: use reverse biased zener diode in output pin of ic regulator. now you have 5v voltage before diode and 3v after it.
use this devices: ic:7805, zener diode 1n4615 or 1n4370.
for better performance add capacitor.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, Yes there are such devices with a single input voltage and multiple output voltages.  By doing a quick research on DigiKey, I was able to come up with a few devices but that will be up to you to find which one is better since shopping recommendation is off-topic.

A simple LDO will typically have one input and one output voltages but it can be designed for multiple outputs.  Instead of 2 chips for different voltages, an electrical design engineer would converge both chips into a single one.  Thus, the die in the chip is bigger and other noises considerations must be taken but I won't get in more details here.

Some parameters to consider would be voltage input, voltage output, number of regulators, voltage dropout, and the package.